# How to restore file from the Recycle Bin to a specific location?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell, recycle-bin

My goal is to restore a specific file from the Recycle Bin to a specified location, i.e. not into its original location. I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/30/10202076.aspx) and also [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/31/10203215.aspx) that explain how to enumerate files currently in the Recycle Bin. But it doesn't show how to do what I need.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. As far as I know, you'll need to restore it to its original location, then use (for example) MoveFile or MoveFileEx to move it to where you want it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: What if there's already a file in the original location?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: [it is possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/01/10204404.aspx) to restore Recycle Bin files to a custom location that is different than the original location.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by simulating drag & drop. Use `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf()` to get an `IDataObject` interface from the recycle bin, and also to get an `IDropTarget` interface for your target folder. Then you can call `IDropTarget::DragEnter()` followed by `IDropTarget::Drop()` and the file will be moved to your target location.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. I was also thinking, since I technically have a path to the file in the recycle bin (hidden) folder, can I just move it out of there with `MoveFileEx`?

Comment: @c00000fd Sure you can, but the recycle bin won't know you've done it, so its internal database will be wrong.

Comment: @c00000fd: This exact scenario is actually covered by Raymond Chen in the following blog article: [Invoking commands on items in the Recycle Bin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/01/10204404.aspx). I guess you missed it when reading Raymond's other Recycle Bin articles that you linked to in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Windows Vista it is possible to use [IFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to restore any object from RecycleBin to any folder. Sample of usage:

```
procedure RestoreItem(AShellFolder: IShellFolder; AChild: PItemIDList; const ADestFolder: UnicodeString);
var
  Item: IShellItem;
  DestFolder: IShellItem;
  FileOperation: IFileOperation;
begin
  OleCheck(SHCreateItemWithParent(nil, AShellFolder, AChild, IShellItem, Item));
  try
    OleCheck(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(PWideChar(ADestFolder), nil, IShellItem, DestFolder));
    try
      OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IFileOperation, FileOperation));
      try
        OleCheck(FileOperation.MoveItem(Item, DestFolder, nil, nil));
        OleCheck(FileOperation.PerformOperations);
      finally
        FileOperation := nil;
      end;
    finally
      DestFolder := nil;
    end;
  finally
    Item := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish I saw it earlier. I went with an old Raymond Chen's code given in the different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Drag & Drop is the way.

Then you can script it in C++, Python, CMD, PowerShell, etc...

[image]